# javascript: Representation for fastest bitwise operations on large bit arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small set (~10) of bitarrays of length ~10,000. What is the bitarray data structure that allows the fastest "AND &" bitwise operations on the entire set?

I'm considering either node.js's Buffer or typed arrays so far. However, it's not clear if either one allows bitwise operations on the entire array or if it must be done using a slow iteration byte by byte.

Comment: This sounds simple enough to benchmark for yourself, no?

Comment: Well, I'm more asking whether there may be better options aside from just these two.